# How can I create a Node Paragraph's image translation programatically?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I'm trying to create a translation on a node's paragraph field whose paragraph contains a text field and an image field. The code below updates the text field as expected but the image field is always blank/empty for the translated node:

```
<?php
   $img[] = array(
            'target_id' => 1029,
            'alt' => 'Translated alt tag',
            'title' => '',
        );
        $desc1[] = array(
            'value' => 'Translated Text',
            'summary' => '',
            'format' => 'basic_html',
        );
        $lang_node->field_images_descriptions->entity
            ->addTranslation($lang_code, [
                'field_product_image' => $img,
                'field_product_description' => $desc1,
            ])
            ->save();
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you set `$img` then try to access `$img1` later.

Comment: Thank you sonfd, that was just a typo in my sample code but my actual code uses the same $variable. I've fixed my question's code.